# Extjs Button Problem:

Tags: extjs

Claim: I am a newbie for Extjs.
I am working on a project by using Extjs.
but confused about for the button setting:

Like

```
var result = action.result;
  if (result.success) {
    Ext.MessageBox.alert('Success',action.result.msg);
  }
  else {
    Ext.MessageBox.alert('Failure',action.result.msg);
  }
```

My question is for the result, what else properties or other function I could use for this 'result', except "success" and "failure"?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ext api doesn't have any specific documentation on the result beyond a vague explanation of what it does, but here is the Action.result [source code](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/dev/docs/source/Action.html#prop-Ext.form.Action-result).  You can look at how success is defined and go from there.

For other questions like this, you should look into the ext [api](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/dev/docs/).  Sencha works hard to document ext well; so you should use that work to your advantage.